# Counting integers of the form $x^4 + y^4$ ??

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, asymptotics, square-numbers

I was intrested in counting Integers of the form $x^4 + y^4$ ( smaller than Some n) both with and without multiplicity.

The Sum of 2 squares analogue is more Well-known.
Gauss circle problem counts essentially these numbers.

Ramanujan-Landau constant relates here too.

A simple combinatorial argument for the bisquare case gives $$\text{density} ( x^4 + y^4) =\frac12 * \text{density}(x^4) * \text{density}(y^4) = \frac12 * n^{1/4} * n^{1/4} = \frac12 * n^{1/2}$$ Or the $K$th Number of that form grows like $4 K^2$.

However I Get stuck at getting better estimates !

The $4$ above is not optimal I think and I wonder about inf and sup of the value $C$ in $C K^2$.

By analogue of the Sum of squares I tried integrals such as

$$ \int 2( t^4 + x^4)^{1/4}\,dx  = t^2 * 2 * 2F_1(-\frac14,\frac14;\frac54;-1) = 2.084... t^2$$

But these values seem wrong.
$2.084$ is way to small , it seems C is more like $\sqrt{27}$ or such.

How to think about this ?

I assume a lim to a value $C$ but Maybe that is wrong ; lim sup might not be lim inf ??

Comment: Yes Will but that Depends on counting multiplicity or not. I already mentioned Ramanujan Landau constant.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, this is very similar to [Gauss circle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem). For any $R\gg\sqrt{2}$, the number $N(R)$ of lattice points in the region $x^4+y^4\leq R^4$ is bounded between the area enclosed by $x^4+y^4\leq (R-\sqrt{2})^4$ and the area enclosed by $x^4+y^4\leq (R+\sqrt{2})^4$.

Since by Euler's Beta function
$$ 4\int_{0}^{1}(1-x^4)^{1/4}\,dx = \tfrac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\,\Gamma\left(\tfrac{1}{4}\right)^2 \tag{A}$$
we have:
$$ N(R) = \tfrac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\,\Gamma\left(\tfrac{1}{4}\right)^2 R^2+O(R^{3/2}) \tag{B}$$
and the number of integers in $[0,N]$ which can be represented as $x^4+y^4$ for $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$, counted according to their multiplicity, is $\tfrac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\,\Gamma\left(\tfrac{1}{4}\right)^2 \sqrt{N}+O(N^{3/8}).$

If we disregard the multiplicity, there cannot be more that $(2n^{1/4})\cdot(2n^{1/4})= 4\sqrt{n}$ integer solutions of $x^4+y^4\leq n$. The exact order of magnitude should be off by a logarithmic factor raised to a very small power, by sieve methods. The smallest number expressible as the sum of two fourth powers in two different ways is
$$ 635318657 = 133^4+134^4 = 158^4+59^4 $$
as [found by Euler](http://euler.free.fr/taxicab4.htm).

---

**Interesting remark**: there is a gap between the count *according to the multiplicity* and the count *disregarding the multiplicity*. In particular, this shows that the function counting the number of representations as a sum of two fourth powers is **unbounded**. Of course, the same holds in the cubic case and proves the existence of [taxicab numbers](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_number) (and their quartic analogues) like $1729=12^3+1^2=10^3+9^3$. The existence of quintic taxicab numbers is unsolved.

Comment: Every part of that needs more explaination imho. Sorry If that is a lot of work.

Comment: But Im still as confused as When I asked

Comment: The sieving for the case x^2 + y^2 was trivial because it was a multiplicative norm and Its prime had a mod property, So sieving half the primes trivially gave sqrt(ln) factor, but nothing like that applies here ?!?

Comment: @mick: you just have to work in a different number field, the idea of approaching $x^2+y^2=N$ through the structure of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ can be generalized (and it leads to higher-order reciprocity laws, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_reciprocity)

Comment: But Z((-1)^(1/4)) is No UFD with multiplicative norm right ?

Comment: @mick: of course, you cannot apply the same old-fashioned techniques for quadratic fields to non-quadratic fields, but that does not mean everything is lost. You may consider the Friedlander-Iwaniec bilinear sieve (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedlander%E2%80%93Iwaniec_theorem), for instance.

Comment: That looks complicated ...

Comment: It is, indeed. But neither Gauss circle problem or the proposed variant are trivial problems, so you should have been prepared to this.

Comment: Better link ??!

Comment: @mick: here it is - https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.01902. Wooley employs the circle method for dealing with a similar problem.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I'm not sure I can follow your argument here. But FYI the attempt at disproof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2473730/11619) backfired. So if you deleted your argument only because it looked like we found a counterexample then, please reconsider.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: actually the argument about the unboundedness of the representation function works in this particular case (if we do not account multiplicity, the represented numbers in $[1,N]$ are $o(\sqrt{N})$). It stops working if we state the same for *any* quartic form $px^4+qy^4$, since there are some parity obstructions. Anyway, no issue here, just considering the quartic form $x^4+y^4$.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: anyway, I seem to recall that the possibility of writing every rational number as $\frac{a^3-b^3}{c^3-d^3}$ was a recent IMO problem.

Comment: In the other thread there is a link to a Dutch set of problems, where that was from. No solution (one way or other).